# When (and how!) to obey the Law of Demeter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm confused to be honest. Apparently you can tie yourself in a knot quite easily in Rails because you can make quite complex queries quite simply and I think I've discovered this.

Here are my relationships:

> **Forum** has_many:belongs_to **Topics**
>
> **Topics** has_many:belongs_to **Posts**
>
> **Topics** has_many:belongs_to **Users**
>
> **User** has_many:belongs_to **Posts**

Now, let's say when a new post is created, I want to email everyone subscribed to the topic that there's a new post. In the email, I give the name of the forum, the name of the topic and the name and body of the post itself. I hand these parameters to the instance method `#notify_all_users` that takes care of the emailing.

Here's how I'm doing it in the PostsController:

```
def create
    @user = current_user
    @post = @user.posts.new(parameters)

    if @post.save
        @post.notify_all_users(post: @post, topic: @post.topic, forum: @post.topic.forum)
    end 
end
```

Now is that violation of the law of demeter? The method chain for the `forum` option has two dots in it, but `dependent :destroy` has been set on `Topic` and `Post`, so a post can't exist if its topic doesn't exist, and a topic can't exist if a forum doesn't exist, so there's zero chance of any nasty nil nil class errors. Should I still take steps to make this obey the Law of Demeter?

Like I say, I've discovered why the Law of Demeter is important the hard way(I think, I'm not sure).

Let's say I browse to my topics page, that shows all of the posts belonging to that topic. Not in violation of the law of the demeter yet!

But let's say that I want so show the username of each post's owner next to the post like this:

```
<div> <%= link_to post.user.user_name, post.user %> </div> 
<div> <%= post.body %> </div>
```

That's in violation of the law of demeter, right?

Because our topic#show action set `@topic`, we looped through `@topic.posts` but now, in that view, we're effectively doing this: `@topic.post.user.user_name` for each post.

Now, is this way LOD is so important? Because if a single user who happens to have a post in the topic  is deleted, the whole app grinds to halt. Nil nil class error because a post no longer has a user class (which of course, doesn't have a user_name).

I thought the way to get round this was to either set up `dependent :destory` in the parent model, or soft_delete a user, but I see I'm just digging further into a hole.

So please, how do I get to obey the law of demeter? In these examples? How should I show the user's name? Should it be saved in the database? So when a user creates a new post, his name is actually stored in the posts table? Then, if a user clicks on the user name, if he is deleted, I can do a rescue `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` in the user#show action?

It seems (to me!) the only way to obey the law is to extensively write all the information we need in the database. So my create actions should look something like this:

```
# post controller
def create
  
    parameters = post_params.merge(user_name: @user.user_name)        

    @user = current_user
    @post = @user.posts.new(parameters)
    
    if @post.save
        # redirect passed validations
    else
        # redirect failed validations
    end
end
```

Now we can do this in the view:

```
<div> <%= link_to post.user_name, user_path(post.user_id) %> </div> 
<div> <%= post.body %> </div>
```

Which, in effect is like writing:

```
@topic.post.user_name
@topic.post.user_id
```

and

```
@topic.post.body
```

Which doesn't disobey the law. Seems kinda perverse to someone whos projects have only just become complex enough to see the importance of LoD when we can get the user so easily with AR (and save a whole table column), but I do see the importance.

Answer (score 1):

As Held mentioned, add a method to your `Post` class. I'd call it, say, `author_name`. Because your system has users, sure, but if you're just looking at a post, the question is basically "who wrote this?" and not "what user record in my system is tied to this particular post record?"

This indirection could also help solve the user-deletion issue in a practical way:

When a user is deleted, you could conceivably go through that user's posts, and set an `author_name` (or something) attribute on each of them. E.g.

```
class User
  # ...
  before_destroy :save_name_to_posts

  private

  def save_name_to_posts
    posts.update_all(author_name: name)
  end
end
```

Now, in the `Post` model, you could do:

```
# you can just use alias/alias_method for this
def author
  user
end

def author_exists?
  author.present?
end

def author_name
  author_exists? ? user.name : super
end
```

So, in your view, you will always have *some* name to tie a post to. You use `author_exists?` to check whether the post's author is still around, so you only do a `link_to` if you have something to link to (or you can use `link_to_if`)

If you don't allow your users to change their name, you can of course add it to the `Post` model immediately. But if they can change it, it's more efficient to only run the update query when they're about to be deleted (instead of every time they change their name).

Comment: Actually `author_name` is what `delegate` was invented for.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Indeed - but there's a branch here. Using `delegate` would raise (or return nil) if `user` isn't there to delegate to

Comment: I don't understand what you mean but this is EXACTLY the case for which delegate was designed. If OP does `delegate :name, prefix: :author, to :user, allow_nil: true` this is expected behaviour to get nil if post has no user (which should never happen BTW)

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel The point is that I'm _not_ explicitly asking for a user. I'm asking for an _author_, and an author may or may not exist (or may or may not even be a user). Adding a level of indirection to allow `Post` to hide the implementation details of what its "author" is. If the idea is that dependent posts get destroyed the moment a user is destroyed, then yes, absolutely use `delegate`. Your assumption is that a missing user "should never happen" - well, what if it should? What if it's desirable? This allows for that.

Comment: @Flambino Seems like a good approach. But what are you thoughts on my first example? Where I'm querying `@post.topic.forum`? On my Topic model should I have class methods that query the forum? A topic can't exist without its forum

Comment: @Starkers For that, there aren't any great solutions. But if a post simply can't exist without a forum, then that's just how it is. Your software can't be infinitely flexible anyway, since it's got to have a specific purpose. LoD, SOLID and other OOP concepts are guides and best practices, but they're not _laws_. They'll help you pick the best solution to a problem or spot trouble ahead of time, which is why you should be aware of them. But they're not solutions in and of themselves. So if your spec says "forum -> topic -> post" then that's just how it is.